# How to play video in streaming by using iOS GoogleDrive SDK?

Tags: ios, youtube, google-drive-api

I want to play video in streaming by using iOS GoogleDrive SDK.
GoogleDrive App in iOS app store can play video in streaming by YouTube.

I have seen this post:
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html
According to the post, the key of play video is the YouTube source link.

The link lists GoogleDrive's all of file properties:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

All file's properties were tried to instead of the YouTube source link, but that doesn't work.
Could anyone tell me how to get the correct link to play video by YouTube?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can the URL in the `embedLink` field to get a streaming player for the video.

Comment: Thanks for your response, "embedLink" I have tried by that post method or using UIWebView. They both don't work, but it is working on desktop browser.